# Link between Document Library and SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-document-library

I have newly created folders for every newly created lists. We have list names and we also have the same folder names inside different document libraries. The user uploads the files inside the newly created folders however can't find any relationship with list items in the properties section once he uploads documents into that folder.

I have tried, content types, lookup columns, attachments neither seems to be working based on my needs.

Would appreciate any suggestions here. I'm using SharePoint Online.

Thanks.

Comment: which type of relationships you would like to maintain between the uploaded documents and list items in lists? Please provide more information on your requirement for better understandment. However, you can create Power Automate - flows on document libraries, so when document is uploaded in that folder you can create new list item in respected list and also set value in lookup column based on uploaded document's ID from document library.

Comment: Hi Dikesh, thanks for your attention. Basically the lists have to be created before the document has been uploaded. Let me clarify better. I go to the document library and inside the document library, I have a folder where I upload my files. Each file has to be linked to the list items where I have more than 30 lists. Basically I can do this using lookup column but lookup column works only for one list. However I have to choose from 6 different lists for one document library. I can create 6 different lookup columns but it is not the efficient way unfortunately.

Comment: For the linking the document with list items from several lists, if you want to show that values as a lookup columns, you can use multi-line text column, where you can store a combo of list and list item id, and using CSR(classic exp) or format json (modern exp) you can set hyperlinks on these values, so it would be displayed similar to multi-lookup column values. In another approach, you can use managed metadata column in document libraries and lists.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation Dikesh, I was thinking about alternative options but using managed metadata seems the best choice. Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation yet to upvote your comment. Appreciated. Edited now I have :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dikesh suggests, using the managed metadata column is a good choice.

If your situation permits, you can actually create a look up column in the list (if the files associated with the list are all stored in the same library).

Or you can add files as attachments to each item.

In addition, you can also use Summary links web part (Classic library).

To use this web part, you need to make sure that SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure is enabled.

[image]

You can create a group for each file, and different groups can add multiple links.

[image]